# How can I insert the id number, of the p param, in a query

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails

This is the param and the query, I need to insert this number in the WHERE of the query. The @p pf the where, doesn´t recieve it

```
 def get_stock
 @p = Proveedor.find(params[:id]) 
  sql5 = "SELECT productos.id as producto,
                 productos.nombre as nombre,
                 productos.stock as cantidad
         FROM proveedors  
         INNER JOIN productos ON proveedors.id = productos.proveedor_id
         WHERE proveedors.id = @p
         GROUP BY productos.id"
 @aux = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql5)
```

end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following. This will suffice your request.

```
def get_stock
  @p = Proveedor.find(params[:id]) 
  sql5 = "SELECT productos.id as producto,
             productos.nombre as nombre,
             productos.stock as cantidad
     FROM proveedors  
     INNER JOIN productos ON proveedors.id = productos.proveedor_id
     WHERE proveedors.id = #{@p.try(:id)}
     GROUP BY productos.id"
  @aux = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql5)  
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 sql5 = "SELECT productos.id as producto,
             productos.nombre as nombre,
             productos.stock as cantidad
     FROM proveedors  
     INNER JOIN productos ON proveedors.id = productos.proveedor_id
     WHERE proveedors.id = #{@p.id}
     GROUP BY productos.id"
```

Hope it helps.